# Error at SolrLoggerUsageEventListener that stop registering statistics

Tags: java, dspace

I have a Dspace 4.2 instalation that throw the following Exception.
The same code work at my PC and other server. This problem avoid statistical data to be registered.

has anyone had a similar problem?

```
  ERROR org.dspace.statistics.SolrLoggerUsageEventListener @
java.lang.NullPointerException
         at 
org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetector.isSpider(SpiderDetector.java:208)
         at 
org.dspace.statistics.util.SpiderDetector.isSpider(SpiderDetector.java:258)
         at 
org.dspace.statistics.SolrLogger.getCommonSolrDoc(SolrLogger.java:287)
         at org.dspace.statistics.SolrLogger.postSearch(SolrLogger.java:469)
         at 
org.dspace.statistics.SolrLoggerUsageEventListener.receiveEvent(SolrLoggerUsageEventListener.java:51)
         at 
org.dspace.services.events.SystemEventService.fireLocalEvent(SystemEventService.java:144)
         at 
org.dspace.services.events.SystemEventService.fireEvent(SystemEventService.java:86)
         at 
org.dspace.app.xmlui.cocoon.SearchLoggerAction.act(SearchLoggerAction.java:65)
         at 
org.apache.cocoon.sitemap.impl.DefaultExecutor.invokeAction(DefaultExecutor.java:55)
         at 
org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.ActTypeNode.invoke(ActTypeNode.java:105)
         at 
org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:55)
         at 
org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.MatchNode.invoke(MatchNode.java:87)
         at 
org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:78)
         at
```

Comment: Using a vanilla 4.2 deployment (checkout from github 4.2 tag), I was unable to reproduce the NPE you reported. Did you customize anything to the files in /config/spiders? Or do you see any differences with the standard 4.2 files in this directory?

https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/tree/6ef03eadd3525177de38511e932c62667959458f/dspace/config/spiders

Comment: It use standard configuration and same code works in other 2 systems without problems. I think it should be some enviroment configuration but dont find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are experiencing following bug:
https://jira.duraspace.org/browse/DS-2355